How to do Join on composite key with postgREST?
I am struggling to find the right syntax to perform a (nested) join on on composite foreign keys.
For example, my tables are
CREATE TABLE post (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, userId TEXT REFERENCES user(id), groupId TEXT REFERENCES group(id));

CREATE TABLE group (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, superGroupId TEXT REFERENCES superGroup(id));

CREATE TABLE userSuperGroupInfo (userId TEXT REFERENCES user(id), superGroupId TEXT REFERENCES superGroup(id), PRIMARY KEY (userId, superGroupId). 

I want to:

Get all post with a certain Id
Get all groups to which the post belongs to (joining on groupId)
Get the user of the post (joining on userId)
Get the (unique if it exists) userSuperGroupInfo. The idea would be to join on userSuperGroupInfo.userId AND userSuperGroupInfo.superGroupId (using group.superGroupId as joining key).

1 to 3 is easy, it's just a regular join. But how do you perform 4? I am struggling to find information on how to express join on composite primary keys (or in general join with more than one ON condition) in postgREST.
For the record, I am using supabase js library, which as far as I understand it's a shallow wrapper around postgREST.
I tried for 4 hours to get this join on composite primary keys to work but I cannot find any information online


Get the (unique if it exists) userSuperGroupInfo. The idea would be to join on userSuperGroupInfo.userId AND userSuperGroupInfo.superGroupId (using group.superGroupId as joining key).

If I understand correctly, you want to JOIN the user table and the group table, using the userSuperGroupInfo as an intermediate one, right?
PostgREST detects certain relationships by default. So, according to your tables, it detects a Many-To-Many relationship between user and superGroup using userSuperGroupInfo as an intermediate table (it references both tables and has a composite PK that includes both FK). It also detects a One-To-Many relationship between superGroup and group.
So, in PostgREST, one way to link user and group would be:
GET /user?select=*,superGroup(group(*))

This is because user and group don't have a direct relationship, so you'll have to nest it this way. To build a custom one you can check Computed Relationships in the docs.

I am struggling to find information on how to express join on composite primary keys (or in general join with more than one ON condition) in postgREST.

As mentioned above, PostgREST detects relationships by default, you can't build custom JOINS directly in the query string. Computed Relationships can be used as an alternative.

Thank you, let me take a look! Although for my use case I would need a function that takes in input 2 things (user, group) and does a join on the composite primary key of the userSuperGroupInfo table. The docs don't really mention this use case, and I'm getting the general feeling that the REST api doesn't like composite keys, so I guess I will transition to use a separate PRIMARY KEY and add a UNIQUE constraints on the two columns which make up the current primary key.

PostgREST does take into consideration composite PK. But it does not find one between user and group because the PK of group (which is group.id) is not referenced in userSuperGroupInfo. That intermediate table references the PK of superGroup (which is superGroup.id), thus allowing a direct relationship between user and superGroup. There is no composite PK that references group in that table, that's why PostgREST cannot detect it directly (only by linking them through superGroup).
